# Extracting 4 items of information of .txt files that are listed via links in an excel

Tags: python, excel

I am new to the forums but have been browsing stackoverflow for  a while now when I had problems while coding.

This time the problem is a little harder and I have absolutely now clue about how to solve it, so here I am asking you for help.

So I got that huge excel with all the SEC 13D filings of investors from the years 1994 to 2001. Each row represents one 13D filing and provides the link (column F) to the SEC Edgar database entry, which opens a .txt with a few pages of information. From that information I need to extract 1. "filed by", 2. "subject company", 3. "Item 2: Identity & Background" and 4. "Item 4: Purpose of transaction".

Here you can see a screenshot of the excel:
[Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3gNX.png)*

*Column G has an entry which needs to be put infront of the lines in column F in order to get to the database entries.

So I was curious, if there was a way to handle all this via python?

Thanks in advance for any help. If further information is needed, please let me know!

EDIT:
The .txt files look like this: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/7536/0000950123-94-001133.txt

Best,
codenoob

Comment: Please add your code trials and errors you got. Also please read [mcve] and follow it in all your posts

Comment: I haven't even tried to code it myself, because I don't know how.